# Is there any way to access C source code in an R package binary?

Tags: r, package, obfuscation

I would like to share my R package but keep the source code until after an article is published. If I compile a package using `R CMD INSTALL --build`, is there any way for an end user to read the C source code?

According to p 44 of [R News 2006-4](http://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf),

> In order to access the sources of compiled code
>   (i.e., C, C++, or Fortran), it is not sufficient to have
>   the binary version of R or a contributed package
>   installed.

I would be satisfied with this knowledge (indeed, I would prefer to release the source), but I need to assuage the fears of my collaborators.

My primary question is to confirm: if I distribute a binary created by `R CMD INSTALL --build`, will the C source be inaccessible?

---

Update: it is not very clear to me why this question has received so many down votes (4 at this point). A downvote indicates "This question has not shown any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I am only asking about native R functionality, not trying to promote any nefarious intent.

Comment: R is an open source. (-1) from me for this question.

Comment: @agstudy why the -1? The alternative is to delay release of the package until publication, which I think would be less desirable.

Comment: I don't think you'll be doing anyone favors by releasing a package that does whatever you claim it does, but saying "sorry you can't see the source to check my claim, nor is there a publication that describes what it does, so just take my word for it that it works and does the appropriate magic"

Comment: @eddi either they can get started on their work now or wait six months. As I said, if it were up to me, I would release it. I am just trying to reach a compromise. In any case, my question is not related to "how useful will it be" or "is it the 'right thing to do'?" but "will the source be accessible or not?".

Comment: @Abe As a compromise you can release 2 versions of your package: light version that you release now with few functionalities , and you complete it once your article is published. But really I found the behavior of your colleagues, they use an open source, in the research domain and they try to hide the code.

Comment: Abe, I was answering to your comment not your question. And to reiterate - I don't think I'd start any serious (presumably scientific) work based on pixie dust, so I think all you achieve by that binary release is "press-coverage".

Comment: @agstudy yes, that is one option that I have considered but more difficult to maintain.

Comment: @eddi It is a bit more complicated than that. Previous versions have been published, and I am only trying to fill a request made by a colleague (with no expectation that anyone will take it on blind faith) to share (and distribute for development and teaching purposes) the more recent version. Notably, I am currently reviewing a paper where all of the analyses were performed in Excel. Unfortunately, there is a large community of scientists (not including myself) who do not share your concerns.

Comment: @eddi [Ince et al 2012](http://211.144.68.84:9998/91keshi/Public/File/34/482-7386/pdf/nature10836.pdf) argue for publishing source code at the time of publication, but I can't find anyone arguing that code should be published prior to publication.

Comment: [fixed link to Ince et al](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v482/n7386/full/nature10836.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the .c source files aren't in the distributed archive file (a .tar.gz for Linux, maybe a .zip for Windows) then no, you can't get the source. I just did a quick test with a skeletal package and a single foo.c file and its not there for me, just a compiled foo.so file.

Unless you've used Rcpp and put the C code into inline R functions, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only binary file output it is inaccessible for source code. Only way to get in to some idea is to disassembly. Of course all of your header files should be also compiled.